# Nginx not returning custom error pages from if expression

Tags: nginx, cdn, custom-error-pages

It's my CDN and conf file contain "few lines".

The situation is really strange:

In configuration i have

```
error_page 403 = /e403;
error_page 404 = /e404;
```

and

```
location =/e403 {
    default_type text/html;
    return 403 "somehtml403";
}
location =/e404 {
    default_type text/html;
    return 404 "somehtml404";
}
```

Same time i have args fitler (args are forbidden, it's a CDN):

```
if ($args !~ ^$){
    return 404;
}
if ($request ~* (^.*\?.*$)){
    return 404;
}
```

When i request `/cookies.txt` i have my custom 404 page. When i request `/cookies.txt?onemore` or `/cookies.txt?` i have nginx's 404 page.

The question is: why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can replicate the problem when the `$if` statements are directly inside the `server` block, but it works correctly when they are inside a top-level location block. This worked for me:

```
location / {
  if ($args !~ ^$){
    return 404;
  }
  if ($request ~* (^.*\?.*$)){
    return 404;
  }
}
```

Of course, if you have other location blocks, you may need to `include` the rules there too.

Comment: It's genial and awesome! Thank you!!